# printing out bool sequence but with int values c++

Tags: c++

i have a sequence that if its true it will count how many sequences are there and just print out the number of sequences, but i want to know how i can print out the actual parameters of the array, cause i have  array[20], and you put in the values and it recognizes how many sequences are there(a sequence is defined as the 4 numbers in ascending order like 23,24,25,26..) and i want to know how i can print out that sequence, not just how many sequences are there. this is a function.

CODE:

```
int sequence(int arr[])
{

    int counter = 1;
    int sequencecounter = 0;
    bool sequence = false;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (!sequence)
        {
            counter = 1;
        }

        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1] - 1)
        {
            counter++;
            sequence = true;
        }
        else
        {
            sequence = false;
        }
        if (!sequence && counter >= 4)
            sequencecounter++;

    }
    return sequencecounter;


}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: the question is how to print out the actual numbers that are a part of that sequence

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stack overflow. Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How to print them? You mean like `std::cout << arr[i]` ..?

Comment: Obviously he means how to adapt his algorithm

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` this is wrong on so many levels... `n` is not defined anywhere, and if it was and assuming this is the number of elements in the array, you will be accessing out of bounds elements with this

Comment: When you determine that `sequence == true`, you can print the previous array values using a loop.

Comment: @UncleDrew when you've found that start of a sequence, save the starting number, when you find the end of the same sequence print all the numbers from the starting number to the ending number you've just found. BTW Think your existing code is bugged, **very** strongly suggest you fix the bugs first, no point writing more code on top of bad code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if you want to print any sequence in any array you should use a cycle
Here's an example of a function that you could use:

```
void print_array(int arr[], int your_array_size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < your_array_size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: why does it only print 3 numbers and not the 4th

Comment: indices are [0, 1, 2, ... , size - 1] so it should print all of your array content anyway

Comment: idk.. it doesnt print the last one. (23,24,25,26) it only prints (23,24,25)

Comment: define size of your array correctly.
that way the function above should work fine 

(or in your case define `n` variable correctly and make sure that `i < n`)

Comment: the array is [20] , its a global const. you put 20 numbers in array and it should just print those in sequence and that is 4 nubmers in a raw, but it only does 3..